# how to write $\iiint_R (x^2+y^2+z^2) dV $ where $R=\{x^2+y^2+z^2\le4, 1\le z\le2\}$

Tags: definite-integrals

How to write $\iiint_R (x^2+y^2+z^2) dV $ where $R=\{x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 4, 1\leq z\leq 2\}$ the limits? I know that $1 \leq z\leq  2$ but for $x, y$ what should be?

**Attempt:**  $y=\sqrt{4-z^2-x^2}$ or $x=\sqrt{4-z^2-y^2}$.

Comment: Do you know about spherical coordinates?

Comment: @Gary how can I write it in that coordinates? Because the order is changed below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

You can also apply the change of variables:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
x = r\cos(\theta)\\\\
y = r\sin(\theta)\\\\
z = z
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Consequently, the region of integration is now given by:
\begin{align*}
R' = \left\{(r,\theta,z) : \left(0\leq r \leq \sqrt{4 - z^{2}}\right)\wedge(0\leq\theta\leq 2\pi)\wedge(1\leq z\leq 2)\right\}
\end{align*}

Finally, one has that
\begin{align*}
I = \iiint_{R}(x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2})\mathrm{d}V = \int_{1}^{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-z^{2}}}r(r^{2} + z^{2})\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta\mathrm{d}z
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

$$\int\limits_{z=1}^2 dz 
\int\limits_{x = -\sqrt{4-z^2}}^{\sqrt{4-z^2}} dx 
\int\limits_{y = -\sqrt{4 - x^2-z^2}}^{\sqrt{4 - x^2-z^2}} dy\ 
f(x,y,z)$$